# How to use ProgressBar from Android 5+ in Android 4.0

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, android-appcompat

I am developing an application for Android 4.0+ using AppCompat and design libraries. And everything looks fine on Android 5.0. But on Android 4.0 I see old progress bar style.

Android 5.0
[image]

Android 4.0
[image]

Xml layout:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/play_seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#fff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Activity declaration:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.PlayListsActivity"
    android:launchMode= "singleInstance"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: You are probably not setting your `Theme` right, for versions below 5.0

Comment: is that progress bar or seek bar?

Comment: It's a seekbar. But in this case it doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version 23.1.0 of the v7 appcompat library added material design `Seekbar` as you can see in the [changelog](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions).

You are probably using an older version  of the v7 appcompat library. Update to the last version and the `SeekBar` will be automatically themed with material design styles like the other widgets.

Change the dependecies of your app `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

    ...
}
```

These are the result obtained on Android 4.4.

With v7 appcompat library v23.0.1:
[image]

With v7 appcompat library v23.1.0:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `AppCompat` is just for `Holo`.But 5.0 is `Material`.
[image]

You can get Widget Like EditText.But you can't get Progress.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Everything on Android 4.0 phone looks like on Android 5.0 phone excluding this seekbar.